# The import javax.annotation.Resource cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc, annotations

I have tried to resolve by adding missing/unnecessary jar's but nothing works for me. if you know how to resolve this issue then kindly help... Thank you in advance.

[image: Code IDE ERROR]

I am using JDK 9.0.4 installed in this IDE Eclipse 4.7 Oxygen December 2017

Windows 10

Servlet 4.0

JSP    2.3

JSTL tags

Comment: Are you sure that the `WebContent\WEB-INF\lib` folder is included in the classpath by your Ide ?

Comment: yes it is all working on other programs fine but when i am working with jdbc but having problem when i am coming to Context XML or  creating a connection pool.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eclipse is facing some bugs in IDE 4.7 it is not fully compitable with JDK 9 like in with JDK 9 IDE is not generating `toString()` function also...

so i change the JDK 9 to jdk 8.1 and it solves all the problem.

to change the JDK...

```
Window > Preferences > Installed JREs >>> Change the JDK 9 to JDK xx
```

AND/OR

```
Right Click Project > Properties > JRE > Edit >>> YOUR ALTERNATIVE JDK xx
```

This had solved my problem.

Comment: Just mention, in Eclipse Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0) " Installed JREs" is located under the "Java" menu point. So, the path to making the aforementioned changes is the following: Window > Preferences >Java >Installed JREs.

Comment: @Otti Indeed thanks for update this comment really helps.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the same problem with you.
Download javax.annotation.jar online and add to your library may help.

Comment: This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Or go to : *right click your project->build path->configure build path->add external JARs->"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\lib\annotations-api.jar"* and all will be right.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using maven managing your dependencies, you can also add the below dependency in your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

OR download the jar file from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2